# Can't access files from within makefile

Tags: make

Whenever I do

```
for f in data/*; echo $f; done
```

from a terminal, it correctly outputs every path.

However, if I add the said line to a makefile, let's say

```
test:
    for f in data/*; echo $f; done
```

and then run `make test`, instead of outputting the files it always outputs an empty string. It does this a number of times equal to the number of files/directories in the directory so it seems to loop correctly.

Why is that?

Edit: I found that doing `$$f` instead of `$f` does the trick but malforms the output if, for example, I use `time` to time the command.

Edit #2: Here's an example of the time command:

from makefile:
`for f in data/ascending_order/*; do time echo $$f; done`

```
data/ascending_order/01/
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.01elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 804maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+232minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

from terminal
`for f in data/ascending_order/*; do time echo $f; done`

```
data/ascending_order/01

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Can you post your current and expected output with the relevant parts ofthe script?

Comment: @vfbsilva I added them.

Comment: you want a shell command into a makefile there is already an anser for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024279/how-to-use-shell-commands-in-makefile ops this is stack not unix. Oki I will add the relavant part
I'm also marking your question as duplicated :)

Comment: Related: [Using the built-in "time" command in bash rather than the external command](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/223221)

Comment: Related: [Differences between reserved word and command \`time\` on shell builtin, function, pipeline and command list?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/269795)

Comment: @vfbsilva Maybe I can't see it but I can't figure out why it malforms my output like that

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux, @Mike! For future reference, try to keep each post about a single question or issue. (You ended up with two here, the `$` escaping and the `time` output.) When you found out about `$$` you could have posted that as an answer too (answering own questions is encouraged.) See the help center for more useful tips on getting the most out of StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue (`echo $f`) is due to escaping inside the Makefile, if you use `$f` then make will think you're referring to the *make* variable instead of the *shell* variable and it will expand that (to empty) which will get your shell to run a single `echo` with a blank line for every file. The solution is to escape the `$` by doubling it, in other words, use `$$f`, in which case make will consume one of the `$`s and pass the shell a `$f`, which is what you want.

---

Regarding the second issue (format of `time` output), what you're seeing is the difference in output format between the bash built-in `time` and the external command `/usr/bin/time`.

make will run the commands in your Makefile by passing them to `/bin/sh`, which some Linux distributions (most notably Debian and Ubuntu) ship pointing to `dash`, which is a simpler shell that doesn't implement a built-in `time` and would end up invoking the external command in that case.

You can get the bash `time` output by telling make to execute the commands in your Makefile using bash, which you can do with this variable assignment in your Makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I've accepted your answer.